# Adding a span icon to a D3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a fairly basic bar chart where I'm trying to have a span icon that appears, anchored at the start of each bar. Which icon appears is dependent on the class of the bar. For example, if the bar is blue, I want a certain icon vs. if the bar is red.

I've appended and added the span which shows up in the console, but is not actually appearing any where in the chart.

I have the icons stored as spans in my css, one for each version of the value name that gets plugged in.

I've tried a variety of selections, ordering, etc. But can't get it to stick.

```
var bars = svg.selectAll('.bar')
.data(data)
.enter().append('g')
.attr('class', 'bar');

bars.append('rect')

var icons = svg.selectAll('rect')
.data(data)
.enter().append("span")
.attr("class", function(d, i) {
    return "icon-" + d.value + "-right";
})
.attr('dx', -6)
.attr('dy', (bar_height / 2) +5)
.attr('text-anchor', 'start');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `foreignObject` element to insert HTML into SVG.

Like so:

```
var icons = svg.selectAll('foreignObject').data(data);
icons.enter().append("foreignObject")
    .attr("class", function(d) { return "icon-" + d.value + "-right"; })
    .append("xhtml:body")
    .append("xhtml:span");
```

Also you can use `text` element to add icons to the SVG:

```
var icons = svg.selectAll('text').data(data);
icons.enter().append("text")
    .html("&#xf00d") // utf-8 character for the icon
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm still having the same issue of it appearing in the source but not actually binding to the page?

Comment: If you use `foreignObject` and they are appearing in the source inside `<svg>` tag then make sure that you position this elements inside svg properly.